# what does this expression mean "val&=val-1"

Tags: c

basically  trying to find hamming string
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance. 
I would like to know what does this expression mean and do `val &= val - 1;`

I know `val+=10-->val=val+10`

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: This isnt Java, looks like C to me

Comment: This doesn't look like Java..

Comment: This is a AND logical operation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction

Comment: @machine_1 those asterisks where only here to emphasize the part of code the user didn't understand

Comment: Lets close this as its been asked before, and all of it, including posted answers are approaching trash quality...

Comment: Why people are down voting the question? It is valid, please do not mark down voted.

Comment: @Nick Likely because it can be answered with a minimum of research/Google "what does &= mean in c" or by reading a beginner-level C book. Also you likely got lots of down votes from tagging this Java; as we can see by the answers posted by the Java programmers, they don't have a clue about this.

Comment: If you edit your question for adding more useful information (a good thing), please be careful not to loose helpful edits by other users. In this case somebody fixed the broken syntax for you and you lost that. On top of that, your edit made the indentation worse. Also, removing largely helpful code is not advisable. The users here are programmers. Quite a lot of them here love code so much that they insist one seeing some in a question and otherwise will not like it. Ideally try to make a [mcve].

Comment: Did you really ask a question to find out what the `&=` operator does? Or did you wonder what the (known) effect of that operator was to achieve in the algorirhm? The latter would be a much more interesting question and (I think) not eligible for being closed as a duplicate. If you have special reasons for "It is valid", then please explain your reasons. Then remember what you read about good questions when you took the [tour] and try to apply those things while [edit]ing your question.

Comment: You're right @Lundin . Guilty as charged :D .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`val` is initialized to

```
val = x ^ y;
```

i.e. `val` is the bit-wise XOR of x and y, which means it contains `1` in all the bits where `x` and `y` differ and `0` in all the bits where `x` and `y` are the same.

Now, each iteration of the loop performs

```
val &= val - 1;
```

which is equivalent to

```
val = val & (val - 1);
```

Each such bit-wise AND operation turns a single `1` bit of `val` to `0`.

For example, suppose the binary representation of `val` is:

```
1010
```

The binary representation of `val - 1` is:

```
1001
```

and after performing bit-wise AND, we get:

```
1000
```

Therefore, by the end of the loop, `dist` contains the number of `1` bits in the original value of `val`, which is the number of bits by which `x` and `y` differ.

Answer (score 3):

```
val &= val - 1
```

Does the following :

Assigns the result of the bitwise AND operation between `val` and `val - 1` to `val`

Comment: Actually there's no "comparison" here... you might want to edit your answer. Cheers.

Comment: @RayToal & machine_1 thanks, edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

***I think, the exact intention is asked for.***

```
val &= val - 1;
```

This removes the right-most, least-significant bit:

```
val:           xxxx1000..000
val - 1:       xxxx0111..111
val & (val-1): xxxx0000..000
```

It typically is used to count (destructively) the number of bits.

The same trick: to get the least significant bit itself, use [Integer.lowestOneBit(val)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#lowestOneBit-int-):

```
int lowestOneBit = val & -val;
```

To understand the latter: `-n == ~n + 1`. That is: a negative number in java is twos-complement: the one-complement (~n) of every bit plus one.

Answer (score 0):

It's equivalent to following one, where & is a bitwise AND.

```
val = val & (val  - 1)
```

Comment: **bitwise** AND

Comment: @Blastfurnace Indeed!

Answer (score 0):

`&=` is a **bitwise AND assignment operator** and it works basically how compound operators (+=, -=, etc) work in most programming languages.

`val &= val - 1;` is same as `val = val & (val - 1);`

A simple '&' comparison is done between *val* and *val - 1* and the result becomes the value of `val`.

Check [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm) for knowledge on more operators in C as well as how to use them.
Merry coding!